# Apache Drill and Apache Kudu - not able to run "select * from <some table>" using Apache Drill, for the table created in Kudu through Apache Impala

Tags: impala, apache-drill, apache-kudu

I'm able to connect to Kudu through Apache Drill, and able to list tables fine. But when I have to fetch data from the table "impala::default.customer" below, I tried different options but none is working for me.

The table in Kudu was created through Impala-Shell as external table.

1. Initial connection to Kudu and listing objects

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/apache-drill-1.19.0/bin$ sudo ./drill-embedded
Apache Drill 1.19.0
"A Drill is a terrible thing to waste."
apache drill> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
|   SCHEMA_NAME     |
+--------------------+
| cp.default        |
| dfs.default       |
| dfs.root          |
| dfs.tmp           |
| information_schema |
| kudu              |
| sys               |
+--------------------+
7 rows selected (24.818 seconds)
apache drill> use kudu;
+------+----------------------------------+
|  ok  |            summary             |
+------+----------------------------------+
| true | Default schema changed to [kudu] |
+------+----------------------------------+
1 row selected (0.357 seconds)
apache drill (kudu)> SHOW TABLES;
+--------------+--------------------------------+
| TABLE_SCHEMA |        TABLE_NAME          |
+--------------+--------------------------------+
| kudu      | impala::default.customer      |
| kudu      | impala::default.my_first_table |
+--------------+--------------------------------+
2 rows selected (9.045 seconds)



apache drill (kudu)> show tables;
+--------------+--------------------------------+
| TABLE_SCHEMA |        TABLE_NAME          |
+--------------+--------------------------------+
| kudu      | impala::default.customer      |
| kudu      | impala::default.my_first_table |
+--------------+--------------------------------+
```

2. Now when trying to run "select * from impala::default.customer ", not able to run it at all.

```
>>>>>>>>>
apache drill (kudu)> SELECT * FROM `impala::default`.customer;
Error: VALIDATION ERROR: Schema [[impala::default]] is not valid with respect to either root schema or current default schema.


>>>>>>>>>
apache drill (kudu)> SELECT * FROM `default`.customer;
Error: VALIDATION ERROR: Schema [[default]] is not valid with respect to either root schema or current default schema.

Current default schema: kudu

[Error Id: 8a4ca4da-2488-4775-b2f3-443b8b4b17ef ] (state=,code=0)
Current default schema: kudu

[Error Id: ce96ea13-392f-4910-9f6c-789a6052b5c1 ] (state=,code=0)
apache drill (kudu)>

>>>>>>>>>


apache drill (kudu)> SELECT * FROM `impala`::`default`.customer;
Error: PARSE ERROR: Encountered ":" at line 1, column 23.

SQL Query: SELECT * FROM `impala`::`default`.customer
                                ^

[Error Id: 5aacdd98-db6e-4308-9b33-90118efa3625 ] (state=,code=0)


>>>>>>>>>
apache drill (kudu)> SELECT * FROM `impala::`.`default`.customer;
Error: VALIDATION ERROR: Schema [[impala::, default]] is not valid with respect to either root schema or current default schema.

Current default schema: kudu

[Error Id: 5450bd90-dfcd-4efe-a8d3-b517be85b10a ] (state=,code=0)

>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Comment: Can you run select * from kudu.`impala::default.customer`. looks like your schemaname is kudu. Not sure why the table is created like this?  If this doesn't work, can you try kudu.customer?

Comment: Hi @KoushikRoy, tried all below again but none work:ed  
apache drill (kudu)> SELECT * FROM kudu.customer;
apache drill (kudu)> SELECT * FROM kudu.`default`.customer;
apache drill (kudu)> SELECT * FROM kudu.impala::`default`.customer;
apache drill (kudu)> SELECT * FROM kudu.'impala::'.`default`.customer;
apache drill (kudu)> SELECT * FROM 'impala::'.`default`.customer;

Comment: Hmm, i think its not able to reach the table.

Answer (score 1):

In Drill conventions, the first part of the `FROM` clause is the storage plugin, in this case `kudu`.  When you ran the `SHOW TABLES` query, you saw that the table name is actually `impala::default.my_first_table`.  If I'm reading that correctly, that whole bit is the table name and the query below is how you should escape it.

Note the back tick before `impala` and after `first_table` but nowhere else.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM kudu.`impala::default.my_first_table`
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Hi @cgivre, Now it connects to the table, but get error:  "apache drill (kudu)> select * from `impala::default.customer`;
Error: INTERNAL_ERROR ERROR: org.apache.kudu.client.NonRecoverableException: Invalid scan stop key: Error decoding composite key component 'id': key too short: <redacted> Fragment: 1:0 [Error Id: 244fbbc4-42ea-40cf-9cc0-ee30caec7eca on ubuntu-VirtualBox:31010] (state=,code=0)
".   Table ==> CREATE TABLE customer(id BIGINT,first_name STRING,last_name STRING, age INT,customer_id STRING,PRIMARY KEY(id)) PARTITION BY HASH PARTITIONS 4 STORED AS KUDU; Same err for any table.

Comment: I'm getting this error for any table,  IMPALA ⇒ select * from my_table_2;
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 99 | sarah |
+----+-------+

DRILL ⇒ select * from `impala::default.my_table_2`;
Error: INTERNAL_ERROR ERROR: org.apache.kudu.client.NonRecoverableException: Invalid scan stop key: Error decoding composite key component 'id': key too short:
Fetched 1 row(s) in 0.53s

Comment: When I created a table thru Kuda Java Client API (thru sample shipped with Kudu), I can see that table and run "Select * .." from that table just fine.  =======>   apache drill (kudu)> select * from `java_example-1633165092635`;
+-----+-----------+--------+
| key |   value   | added  |
+-----+-----------+--------+
| 0   | null   | 12.345 |
| 4   | null   | 12.345 |
| 20  | null   | 12.345 |

Comment: @vikaskumar, it seems like you are doing a few different things here.  Are you able to successfully query a Kudu table from Drill with either a `SELECT *` or `SELECT field1, field2...`?   If you're not able to do this, could you please enable verbose errors and post the full stack trace?

Comment: It worked finally, but with a caveat. I created yet another test table "WITH PRIMARY KEY AS STRING instead of BIGINT".  |||CREATE TABLE test_table3(id STRING,name STRING,PRIMARY KEY(id, name)) PARTITION BY HASH PARTITIONS 4 STORED AS KUDU;|||
----|||INSERT INTO test_table3 VALUES (“99”, "sarah");||| ---- ||| apache drill (kudu)> select * from `impala::default.test_table3`;+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 99 | sarah |
+----+-------+
1 row selected (0.42 seconds). >>>> But at least I can narrow down to the issue on why not with BIGINT as the PK, will try more. Thnx

Comment: Able to narrow down even further, so far the issue seems to be with only BIGINT being the data type for the PK. Created another table with INT as key and it worked fine. ==> "CREATE TABLE test_table5
(
  id INTEGER,
  name STRING,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
PARTITION BY HASH PARTITIONS 4
STORED AS KUDU;
" >>>>>> "apache drill (kudu)> select * from `impala::default.test_table5`;
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 99 | sarah |
+----+-------+
1 row selected (0.712 seconds)
" >>> Created another table with BIGINT, it gives the same error, so there is issue with BIGINT PK/DRILL

Comment: Could you please file an issue at Drill's github or at issues.apache.org?  Seems like something that could be fixed fairly easily.

Comment: Issue created - https://github.com/apache/drill/issues/2323